# Import error ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns/AdapterDateFns.js 58:0-65

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns/AdapterDateFns.js 58:0-65
Module not found: Error: Package path ./_lib/format/longFormatters is not exported from package C:\Users\ykd\git\BookHaircutApp\frontend-react\node_modules\date-fns (see exports field in C:\Users\ykd\git\BookHaircutApp\frontend-react\node_modules\date-fns\package.json)

my imports :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import { PickersDay } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersDay';
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check';
```

Comment: did you look at the exports field in `C:\Users\ykd\git\BookHaircutApp\frontend-react\node_modules\date-fns\package.json)` - check [this issue with x-date-pickers](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11454) for info

Comment: yes, i have    "date-fns": "^3.3.1", imported in my package.json.

Comment: so, yes you know what to do now